# How to add new column to MYSQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, addition, alter

I am trying to add a new column to my MYSQL table using PHP. I am unsure how to alter my table so that the new column is created. In my assessment table I have:

```
assessmentid | q1 | q2 | q3 | q4 | q5
```

Say I have a page with a textbox and I type `q6` in to the textbox and press a button then the table is updated to:

```
assessmentid | q1 | q2 | q3 | q4 | q5 | q6
```

My code:

```
<?php 
  mysql_query("ALTER TABLE `assessment` ADD newq INT(1) NOT NULL AFTER `q10`");
?>
  <form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="newq" size="20">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: RTLM: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Comment: Im unsure how to word my query, I have this and it does not work..

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM assessment");

if (!$sql){

mysql_query("ALTER TABLE `assessment` ADD `q6` INT(1) NOT NULL AFTER `q5`");


echo 'Q6 created';

}ELSE{

//from here just continue the page as usual!

echo 'Q6 already exists!';

Comment: @StevenTrainor comments are not the best place for source code. If you are showing where you are having your problem it should be a part of the question. Could you edit your question to include the source?

Comment: bad code. mysql_query will return boolean false on ANY failure, not just when you're trying to add a duplicate field. always check `mysql_error()` to see what went wrong. e.g. `$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());`.

Comment: What does this question have to do with PHP?

Answer (score 260, accepted):

your table:

```
q1 | q2 | q3 | q4 | q5
```

you can also do

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD q6 VARCHAR( 255 ) after q5
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked with - mysql_query("ALTER TABLE `assessment` ADD `q6` INT(1) NOT NULL AFTER `q5`");

Comment: How can i name the column whatever name i type into a textbox?

Comment: if you mean a simple html form textbox, you can do it by getting the post or get parameters on the form target page

Comment: How do i do that? I will amend my code above to what i have now and if you could tell me where im going wrong that would be great :)

Comment: the value of the text box should be in $_POST['newq'] after you submit

Comment: @StevenTrainor: Do **not** use the string in your text box as such in the SQL statement. You must make sure you escape it in order to avoid an SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: It's 2015 and people are still trying to set themselves up for sql injection vulnerabilities—:facepalm:

Comment: I use this command in a loop on an array which contains the name of the column but just the first column is created, however the array is full. any idea what I'm doing wrong? I could have ask it as a new question but first wanted to check it out here. thanks a lot.

Comment: @dima instead of "the value of the text box should be in $_POST['newq'] after you submit " should suggest to use securty safe way to bind values, so data is escaped, else can get sql injection ... i know its not part of the question but should be part of a good answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: @steven-trainor and anyone else do see https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score 10):

```
 $table  = 'your table name';
 $column = 'q6'
 $add = mysql_query("ALTER TABLE $table ADD $column VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL");
```

you can change `VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL` into what ever `datatype` you want.

Comment: Got it thanks, how can i name the column whatever name i type into a textbox?

Comment: @StevenTrainor what do you mean by `textbox`? if you mean an `input` what `type='text'` write `$column = $_POST['textbox'];`

Comment: @StevenTrainor first you need to name your input `name='textbox'` or change textbox in `$column = $_POST['textbox'];` to the name of the input...

Answer (score 9):

- You can add a new column at the end of your table

  `ALTER TABLE assessment ADD q6 VARCHAR( 255 )`
- Add column to the begining of table

  `ALTER TABLE assessment ADD q6 VARCHAR( 255 ) FIRST`
- Add column next to a specified column

  `ALTER TABLE assessment ADD q6 VARCHAR( 255 ) after q5`

and more options [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

Answer (score 4):

Something like:

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
$name = $db->mysqli_real_escape_string($name);
$query = 'ALTER TABLE assesment ADD ' . $name . ' TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\'';
if($db->query($query)) {
    echo "It worked";
}
```

Haven't tested it but should work.

Comment: Thanks - How can i name the column whatever name i type into a textbox?

Comment: Replace my `$name` assignment with: `$name = $db->mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['input']);` assuming you submit your form normally. If it's ajax it's a little more complex.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into normalizing your database to avoid creating columns at runtime.

Make 3 tables:

1. assessment
2. question
3. assessment_question (columns assessmentId, questionId)

Put questions and assessments in their respective tables and link them together through assessment_question using foreign keys.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment it looks like your'e only adding the new column if: `mysql_query("SELECT * FROM assessment");` returns false. That's probably not what you wanted. Try removing the '!' on front of $sql in the first 'if' statement. So your code will look like:

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM assessment");
if ($sql) {
 mysql_query("ALTER TABLE assessment ADD q6 INT(1) NOT NULL AFTER q5");
 echo 'Q6 created'; 
}else...
```

Answer (score 1):

for WORDPRESS:

```
global $wpdb;


$your_table  = $wpdb->prefix. 'My_Table_Name';
$your_column =                'My_Column_Name'; 

if (!in_array($your_column, $wpdb->get_col( "DESC " . $your_table, 0 ) )){  $result= $wpdb->query(
    "ALTER     TABLE $your_table     ADD $your_column     VARCHAR(100)     CHARACTER SET utf8     NOT NULL     "  //you can add positioning phraze: "AFTER My_another_column"
);}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE `stor` ADD `buy_price` INT(20) NOT NULL ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the ALTER TABLE in the PHP code is in this line:

mysql_query("ALTER TABLE assessment ADD newq INT(1) NOT NULL AFTER q10");

It should be AFTER q5 since there is no q10 in your table sample. So, it becomes
ALTER TABLE assessment ADD newq INT(1) NOT NULL AFTER q5;