# Insert into specific column mysql database php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I want to enter data into my mysql db but into a specific row, when the user enters a number and clicks a button. For example, if the user logged in, is called 'user', then the data which is entered will go into a column called 'ticket' which is in the same row as the username 'user'.

I have written the code for it to go into the db but in a new row:

Code for page which user enters the data:

```
<?php require('check.php')?>
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $row['username']; ?> Profile</title>
</head>
<body>
<p style="float: right"><a href="logout.php">LOG OUT</a></p>
<?php
include ('connect.php');

$user_id= $_SESSION['id'];
$sql = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE user_id = '$user_id'";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Query failed. ' . mysql_error());
$uname = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$user_id= $_SESSION['id'];
$sql = "SELECT email FROM user WHERE user_id = '$user_id'";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Query failed. ' . mysql_error());
$uemail = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo "Hello" . " " . $uname['username'];
?>


             <h1>Choose ticket Amount</h1>
             <hr />
             <form method="post" action="addticket.php">
             <label for="elliegoulding">Ellie Goulding Ticket Amount: </label>
             <input type="text" name="elliegoulding" max="3" maxlength="3" /><br />
             <br />
             <input type="submit" value="Add ticket"/>
             <br />
             <hr />
             <div id="footer">
             </div>
         </form>



</body>
</html>
```

Code for php page which processes information and adds to db:

```
<?php
$elliegoulding = $_REQUEST["elliegoulding"];


$linkme = mysql_connect("mysql.cms.gre.ac.uk","ta210","*****");
if (!$linkme)
    die ("Could not connect to database");
mysql_select_db("mdb_ta210", $linkme);

$query = "INSERT INTO user (ticket) VALUES ('$elliegoulding, Ellie Goulding Tickets')";
mysql_query ($query, $linkme)
    or die ("Ticket purchase failed.");

echo ("You have just bought $elliegoulding Ellie Goulding tickets");

mysql_close($linkme);
?>
```

Like I said the above code works and enters it into the database but just into a new row.
Any help or suggestions would be great.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add new column to MYSQL table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113570/how-to-add-new-column-to-mysql-table)

Answer (score 2):

INSERT will only add a new row and you don't want that. You need to UPDATE the row.

Something along the line of... :

```
$query = 'UPDATE user SET ticket="Ellie Goulding rocks!" WHERE username="'.$user.'"';
```

Make sure that username is unique (can't have 2 "Pierre" in your database or both users will get updated).