# How to add (ALTER table_name) in my code

Tags: php, jquery, sql

Is it possible to add new field without editing my database but using PHP code or jquery to insert new field in my database, so let's say i have a table name `MAIN` with `(COL1 ,COL2)` and in my PHP code/jquery will insert new field `(COL 3)` in my database. Is it possible?

```
$result=("SELECT * FROM main");
$res = $conn->query($result);
if(isset($_POST['Add'])){
    if(empty($_POST['ParentCreate'])){
        echo "Fill up the textbox";
    }else{
        $sql = "ALTER TABLE tablemain ADD COLUMN
'".$_POST['ParentCreate']."' VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COMMENT '' AFTER
main_one";
    $conn->query($sql);
    echo "New Field created";
}

}
-----------------------------------
<body>
<div id="frm_div">
    <form id="frm1" action="">
        <input type="text" name="ParentCreate" placeholder="ParentCreate" />
        <input type="submit" name="Add" value="Add" />
    </form>
</div>
<div id="result">
<?php
if($res!=""){
while($row=$res->fetch_row()){
    echo $row[0]."<br/>";
    echo $row[1]."<br/>";

}   
 }else{
    echo "Nothing Found";
 }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Show some code or what you've tried so far

Comment: something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113570/how-to-add-new-column-to-mysql-table

Comment: @Lucabro thanks for the link

Answer (score 1):

First have a look at this: [W3 Schools | SQL ALTER](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp)

### Explanation

The SQL Code you are looking for:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD column_name datatype [AFTER previous_column_name]
```

[AFTER] -> optional, default at the end.

In your case it's (let's suppose the datatype for COL3 is VARCHAR):

```
ALTER TABLE MAIN
ADD COL3 VARCHAR(30) [AFTER previous_column_name]
```

If you do not even know how to use mysqli in PHP have a look at the 
[PHP.net MySQLi Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)
(Alternative: php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php)

But watch out! PHP will drop support for MySQL, so you better use MySQLi.

### Update 1 - Fire a mysql Query

Get connected with the Host:

```
$conn = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) 
        or die("Failed to connect to Database: " . mysql_error());
```

Select the Database:

```
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $conn) 
      or die("Failed to select Database: " . mysql_error());
```

Define your Query:

```
$sql = "ALTER TABLE tablemain 
        ADD '".$_POST['ParentCreate']."' VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL AFTER main_one";
```

Fire your Query:

```
mysql_query($sql) or die("Failed adding column: " . mysql_error());
```

Comment: @acooshot So you got it? I really would appreciate a +1 on my post - I'm new. :) I already updated my answer with step-by-step instructions. Maybe it's more helpful. :)

Comment: sorry it says that i need 15 reputation first  :
Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post