# How to alter table in MySql and add column in Java?

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to add a column to my table but I'm getting an error saying my syntax is wrong. I'm stuck, any ideas on correct syntax at line 2 on here?

```
String myColumnType = "DECIMAL";
st.executeUpdate("ALTER TABLE stocks.stockvalue ADD " + myColumnName + " " + myColumnType);
String updateTableSQL = ("UPDATE stocks.stockvalue SET stockvalue." + myColumnName + " = ? WHERE stockvalue.stockvalue_id = " + count);
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(updateTableSQL);
preparedStatement.setDouble(2, stockV);
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
System.out.println("Done");
preparedStatement.close();
conn.close();
```

Comment: **Post the error message.** And shouldn't it be `ALTER TABLE foo ADD COLUMN`?

Comment: Next time check the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html).

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '12/12/2016 DECIMAL' at line 1

Comment: I made it ALTER TABLE stocks.stockvalue ADD COLUMN and still have the error.

Comment: this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113570/how-to-add-new-column-to-mysql-table?rq=1 can help

Comment: @Zack Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a Q&A site, not a forum. Please click the green mark on the left side of the answer that solved your question, that will mark it as the accepted solution. We do that instead of editing the title to add "solved", which is usual in forum format.

Comment: Honestly, why would you make another column? If that is to solve one to many realation, you should make another table instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for adding column to existing table is

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
  ADD column_name column-definition;
```

For example ,

"ALTER TABLE  stockvalue ADD " + myColumnName + " " + myColumnType

I think you missed word TABLE in statement. 
Try it. Hope this help you..

Comment: Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '12/12/2016 DECIMAL' at line 1

Comment: I figured out it's probably the table name, can I not have the date as the table name? Such as "12/12/16"?

Comment: Yes I guess. Try changing column name to some dummy name.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I had to change the date from 12/12/16 to 12_12_16. Thank you :) .

Comment: Hey if your problem got solved then please accept my answer.. thanks

Comment: @Zack: please accept this answer, by clicking on the tick icon to the left. This is how we thank people on Stack Overflow, and how we mark questions as resolved. Thanks!